# Deserializing object[] that contains primitive types and one class type

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have an object array that contains strings and longs and this class:

```
public class SimpleMailAddress
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator MailAddress(SimpleMailAddress m)
    {
        return new MailAddress(m.Address, m.Name);
    }
}
```

However, when deserializing the JSON array with Json.Net, I get an anonymous type that contains `Address` and `Name` instead of a `SimpleMailAddress` object.

I don't want to create a strongly-typed object to deserialize into because it will not be reused and I'd have to create a lot of objects for it. Is there a way to do this with Json.Net or any other library?

This is how I'm serializing/deserializing:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MailMessageRequest>(json);
```

And `MailMessageRequest`:

```
public class MailMessageRequest
{
    public string Mailer { get; set; }
    public string Method { get; set; }
    public object[] Args { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that shows how you serialize and deserialize

Comment: Can you also add a sample of the Json? And I think your question is a bit unclear. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to deserialize into anonymous object or `SimpleMailAddress`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Json does not contain any inherit knowledge about your `SimpleMailAddress` class.  So when you are telling it to deserialize, the fact that your Args property is of type `Object`, the deserializer is doing the best it can (by creating an anonymous type).  It just sees data, it has no knowledge that you want a `SimpleMailAddress` object.

Json.net has a `JObject` class.  Try using that instead of Object for your Args parameter if the actual contents of Args may change type.

Then, as needed, you can read the data from the `JObject` object.

If you don't care about the actual contents of Args, then leave it as `Object` and ignore it.

**Edit:** JSon.Net can embed type information during serialization that can be used during deserialization.

Leave your `Args` parameter as an `Object`.  Then use the `TypeNameHandling` option of `All` during both serialization and deserialization.

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject, Formatting.None, 
    new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All });
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MailMessageRequest>(json, 
    new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All });
```

You should end up with your `Args` object as your desired `SimpleMailAddress` object.

Comment: I've tried deserializing using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All })` as well, which specifies the types, but it still deserializes it into a `JObject`.

Comment: Ahh, sweet, good work. I figured that out just as you did ;) I'm actually not sure if I need the `TypeNameAssemblyFormat` that I included, though.

Answer (score 0):

The data contact serializers built into the.net framework have the concept of known types where you tell them what types to expect and it uses those during deserialization.

There is a built in Json data contract serializer but I'm not sure it will be compatible with your Json data, it may need to be serialized and deserialized via a datacontract serializer to work using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I have to use these settings:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
               {
                   TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
                   TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full
               };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object, Formatting.None, settings);
var object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MailMessageRequest>(message.Body, settings);
```